# Trigger a release after a succesful release

Tags: azure-devops

My Scenario:

I got several release pipelines in azure devops each one deploying its own application. Now these applications use each others api:s. So when a deployment is done they run a system test. So each release pipeline have a shared task group with system tests in their pipeline. Usully a deployment succeds but sometimes the system tests does not so the whole release will fail even when a deployment is done. Which annoys me.

Now I want to move this system tests to its own release pipeline and it will be triggered when a deployment is done. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Azure PowerShell task at the end of the first release job. So that when first release job completed it triggers the second release job. Just pass the second job definition id.

PowerShell :

```
Param(
   [string]$vstsAccount = "software",
   [string]$projectName = "project",
   [string]$definitionId = "895",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$personalAccessToken  = "xxxxxx"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT)
$headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)")) }

# Construct the REST URL
$uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$vstsAccount/$projectName/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0-preview.8"

Write-Host "Uri :" $uri

$params = 
@"
{
    "definitionId": $definitionId,
    "description": "Create Release from PowerShell Script",
    "artifacts": [],
    "isDraft": false,
    "reason": "VSTS Trigger",
    "manualEnvironments": null,
    "environmentsMetadata": null, 
    "properties": null, 
    "variables": null
}
"@

Write-Host "Request Body :" $params

# Invoke the REST call and capture the results
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $params -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Verbose -Debug

Write-Host "Result :" $result

# This call should only provide a single result
if ($result.count -eq 0)
{
    Write-host "Unable to locate Release Definition Id $definitionId"
}
else
{
    Write-host "Successfully triggered the VSTS release job !!!"
}
```